# CartThrob Price Modifier Question

Tags: cartthrob

I am trying to display information stored in a price modifier column I added called {option_color}. Can someone help me? I tried the following but didn't work:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form
        class='form-horizontal'
        name="productView"
        entry_id="{entry_id}"
        no_tax="{no_tax}"
        no_shipping = "{no_shipping}"
        return="store/view_cart"} 

    {exp:cartthrob:item_options field="envelope_options" entry_id="{entry_id}" row_id="{row_id}"}
        {option_label}: {option_color}
    {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}

{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

Comment: What does 'didn't work' mean? No output, incorrect output? Have you got a channel entries tag wrapping the add_to_cart_form tag? Does the channel entries tag output any other data?

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question...

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form entry_id="{entry_id}"}

  {envelope_options}
    {option_name} {option_color}
  {/envelope_options}

{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use Matrix to create my price modifiers, over the CT Price Modifier field type.

It's Much more flexible in terms of added extra options.